# While "ionic serve" Getting message Install your Cordova CLI to version >=4.2.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Though I have installed cordava --version is `6.0.0` I get this below message while I run ionic application "`ionic serve`"

```
Please install your Cordova CLI to version >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`
```

Comment: what result does cordova --version on cmd prompt says? u could install a specific version of cordova by executing npm install -g cordova@6.0.0

Comment: Did you install cordova globally?

Comment: @kolli yes it's installed globally while installing ionic `$ npm install -g cordova ionic`

Comment: @lamKarin the result for `cordova --version` is `6.0.0`

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ionic info` to see current version

```
npm install -g cordova@6.0.0
```

That should do the trick as it is seems 6.1.0 isn't a stable version.